# Spring WebFlux: WebSocketSession.send() doesn't send messages

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-webflux, spring-websocket

Helloc
I am trying to create webscoket endpoint using Spring WebFlux. I want this endpoint to return some events.
In order to do so I created ConnectableFlux of events and in handle(..) method I map it to Flux. But after I give it to WebSocketSession, nothing happens - websocket client doesn't receive anything. But at the same time println(event.toString()) which you can see in my handle(..) method below actually prints information to console.
Could you please tell what am I missing?

```
public class EventWebsocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    //  constructors and etc.

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Flux<WebSocketMessage> messages = eventService.events()
                .flatMap(event -> {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(event.toString());
                        return Mono.just(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(event));
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        return Mono.error(e);
                    }
                })
                .map(session::textMessage);

        return session.send(messages);
    }

@Service
public class EventService {

    List<EventDto> events = new ArrayList<>();

    private final Flux<EventDto> eventFlux = Flux.<EventDto>create(fluxSink -> {
        while (true) {
            if (!events.isEmpty()) {
                fluxSink.next(events.get(0));
                events.remove(0);
            }
        }
    })
            .publish()
            .autoConnect();

    public void push(EventDto event) {
        events.add(event);
    }

    public Flux<EventDto> events() {
        return eventFlux;
    }

}
```

I have another WebSocketHandler in my project and it works fine, which means everything is OK with configuration:

```
public class MyWebSocketHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> handle(WebSocketSession session) {
        Flux<Long> source = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(1000 * 3));
        return session.send(source.map(l -> session.textMessage(String.valueOf(l))));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
    private final Flux<EventDto> eventFlux = Flux.<EventDto>create(fluxSink -> {
    while (true) {
        if (!events.isEmpty()) {
            fluxSink.next(events.get(0));
            events.remove(0);
        }
    }
})
        .publish()
        .autoConnect();
```

Has to be replaces with this

```
private final Sinks.Many<EventDto> processor = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
```